# Using forEach method with Array to build navigation menu and unordered list with JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to generate an unordered list and also navigation bar using JavaScript.

This is the JS snippet I have  (looping through an Array using a forEach method):

```
const navMenu = document.querySelectorAll("page_header");
const navList = document.getElementById("menu_list");
const items = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("section"));
items.forEach((item, i) => {

    const listItem = document.createElement("li");
    listItem.classList.add("menu-item");
    const anchorTag = document.createElement("a");
    anchorTag.innerText = item;
    const sectionName = item.getAttribute('data-nav');
    const sectionID = item.getAttribute('id');
    listItem.innerHTML = createNavItemHTML(sectionID, sectionName);
    navList.appendChild(listItem);

});
```

I also want to rewrite this function somehow since I took it straight off from a github repo that I am not comfy taking straight off.

```
 function createNavItemHTML(id, name) {
        const itemHTML = `<a class ="menu__link" data-id="${id}">${name}</a>`;
        return itemHTML;
    }
```

I simply want to include an anchor tag in my unordered list for each list item. But cannot get it to work...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `anchorTag.innerText = item;` are you trying to put `section` elements into `a` elements? You cannot assign objects to `innerText`. Please add information as of what functionality you are trying to implement.

Comment: Oh, good question. This is a mistake I guess. I want to create my list items as "clickable" links. Directing them to relevant section on the page.

Comment: Those sections all have `id` and `data-nav`?

Comment: Yes, they all have.

Comment: Thanks @connexo for your input and clarification on innerText. The main functionality is to create an unordered list and present it in a navbar with anchor links to each section. The id's and data-nav attributes are retrieved from each of the 6 sections. 
I tried your snippet below and it works. Will just have to adjust so they are presented as a horizontal navBar. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code alot:

```js
const navList = document.getElementById("menu_list");
const sections = document.querySelectorAll("section");
for (const section of sections) {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.className = "menu-item";
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.textContent = section.dataset.nav;
    a.href = `#${section.id}`;
    li.appendChild(a);
    navList.appendChild(li);
};
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for a swift and crisp response. @connexo Very much appreciated. I  am new to this so excuse me for asking, but is it ok to use this snippet in my project, accrediting you of course?

Comment: That is trivial code, no need for attribution :)